# Not able to open second activity from first activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Here is the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paidquery.mobile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is login Activity java file, where I am writing on click function and this is also my first activity. I see both the console log in my console but whenever do click on signup button, Application go close itself and give the error in console which says couldn't find sign up activity.

```
package com.paidquery.mobile;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static final String LOGIN_TAG = "login_msg";
    private static Button sign_up_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        onClickSignUpBtnListner();
        Log.i(LOGIN_TAG, "Login onCreate function");
    }

    /** Sign up button click function */

    public void onClickSignUpBtnListner() {

        Log.i(LOGIN_TAG,"In onClickSignUpBtnListner call");
        sign_up_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);

        sign_up_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Here is latest console log error when i click on sign up button of login activity.

01-13 16:25:18.844 28104-28104/com.paidquery.mobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.paidquery.mobile, PID: 28104
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paidquery.mobile/com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                                                                          at com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:17)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Check manifest.xml. To declare SignUpActivity  in it.

Comment: is your manifest contains `SignUpActivity` activity?

Comment: This below is the manifest file.

Comment: How can we help without any code?

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: This is my sign up activity xml in manifest file. I am using "com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity" as Intent on my first activity's button click.

Comment: Post the code where you're creating the intent of SingUpActivity.

Comment: Here is the onClick functionality code:                                                                     sign_up_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        );

Comment: Please post your code with edits on your original post - not in the comments!

Comment: From which activity are you calling SignUpActivity..??

Comment: Please share your signUp activity as it may be because of title setting in activity it is giving null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 2):

Please read carefully [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) constructors.

You're using [Intent (String action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)) (`new Intent("com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity")`) to start your second activity.

Androdi will assume that `com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity` is an **Intent action Filter**,which is not available in your manifest.xml file.

Change your code to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paidquery.mobile/com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity}

Comment: Try to remove <intent-filter> tag (with his actions) for the SignUpActivity in manifest.

Comment: Removed. Main post updated with latest code. Same Error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paidquery.mobile/com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity}

Comment: Update the complete console log in main post in bottom.

Comment: Its another problem **NullPointerException**, i think your Toolbar object is null so when you call *Toolbar.getTitle()* you get the NullPointerException.

Comment: Actually in SignUpActivity, when I do remove this code it do work. otherwise not and give the same error in console. "Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar);"

Comment: It's another problem, you should open a new question to not confuse future users.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments to your OP, we need code.

However, this is the most common way to **start an Activity** from an **Activity**.

Assume the following :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button sign_up_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_btn);
        sign_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start activity sign up here :
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
}
```

However, also as stated in the comments, you have to declare every Activities in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Inside the `<application> </application>` scope, your **SignUpActivity** as follows :

```
<activity android:name="SignUpActivity"/>
```

Make sure that you write the name of the package that contains this activity if you placed it in a specific package. No need to write down the your application package as it should be declared in the manifest as well.

Make also sure that there is a proper import inside your calling activity (in my example, the `MainActivity`) but Android Studio should help you with that.

## [UPDATE 1]

Given your crash log and your comments, the error is that your **ToolBar** inside your **SignUpActivity** does not exist so when you try to find it returns **null**.

This is because the them of your SignUpActivity declared in your AndroidManifest file is set to remove the ToolBar :

`<activity [...] android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> </activity>`

Therefore you should use another theme. To do so, modify your **styles.xml** file where `AppTheme` is defined and change for something like this :

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.DarkActionBar">`

And voilà you can now use the ToolBar in your SignUpActivity.

Comment: As explained in my answer : 1) no need to specifiy the package that contains your **SignUpActivity** if it is the same as stated in the beginning of your **AndroidManifest**. Please remove `"com.paidquery.mobile"`. 2) The way you create the **Intent** is used for actions wich is not what you want to do. Try as follows : `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class)`. It should work as stated in my answer.

Comment: I have updated the main post wit current code again. Not working, Error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paidquery.mobile/com.paidquery.mobile.SignUpActivity}

Comment: Update the complete console log in main post in bottom.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also post the content of the **onCreate()** method of your `SignUpActivity` ? and also, please place the stack error code in SO code for better readability

Comment: Actually in SignUpActivity, when I do remove this code it do work. otherwise not and give the same error in console.                                   "Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);"

Comment: If I remove that code, it remove my toolbar from signup activity. what to do if I want to keep the same toolbar.

Comment: Well the problem is that the **ToolBar** is null (hence the nullpointer exception in you crash log) because the **theme** of your `SignUpActivity` is `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` which removes the ToolBar in this Activity. That's all! If you want to keep the toolbar, change this activity theme so it uses the ToolBar ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Its crashes because `SignUpActivity.java` line no 17.** .

I think you are trying to set custom `actionbar` / `toolbar` but which is not mention in your second xml (for SignUpActivity).